# Import dynamically a dart file from a command line argument

Tags: command-line, dart

Is it possible to have something like:

```
dart cmdtool.dart -f another_dart_file.dart
```

And being able to parse and execute the file provided as argument inside the `cmdtool.dart`?

I explored the `Isolate` scenario but i'm not sure it's the best approach.
Thoughts?

Comment: I think Isolate is the best bet.

Comment: Could you give more details about what you want to do with the input file?

Comment: Sure. The `cmdtool.dart` gets another dart file from the command line call as an argument and is able to execute, for example, the main function inside that file (main should be easier but the perfect scenario would be to being able to eval all its content). I've read about the postponing of dynamic imports in dart, like, in nodejs, using `require` in the middle of the code or, from ES7 import: `import()`.